# What is the best way to design a weather forecast (hourly/daily)

Tags: website-design, web

I've been experimenting with some different formats. This is for a web interface.

Give the following data points to show:

**Hourly**:

- Forecast Icon
- Forecast Text
- Temp
- Precip

**Daily**:

- Same data but also for night

What would be the best way to design these. For hourly I like the way http://www.weather.com/weather/today/ does it but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Then for the daily forecast I thought what if it was designed vertically like a calendar. With each day expandable. Or is it better to keep it consistent with the hourly design.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is a bit broad and subjective here. What criteria will you use to judge 'best'? As it's written you're really just asking us to all submit ideas and you'll vote for your favourite. That's not really what this site is for. What design have you come up with already? And what is wrong with that design? We can help you solve your own issue, but can't do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [UK Meteorological Office App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.gov.metoffice.android&hl=en_GB) makes a pretty good job of the basic interface: the colour coding of the temperatures is a nice touch